# checkbox disable based on check in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hi i have two condition on checkbox value so while check

```
i)if user click "no record " other checkbox had to disable  or
ii)it have to alert only no record have to select like that or
iii) while click of no record other selection have not allowed to check
```

my code:

```
<tr class='tablecolor-L-TD' id="+sno+">" +
              "<td class='lc_sno_1' ><center> "+sno+"</center></td>"+
              "<td class='lc_survey_1' ><center> "+v.surveyNo+"</center></td>" +
              "<td class='lc_subdiv_1' ><center> "+v.subdivNo+"</center></td>" +
              "<td class='lc_ExtAres_1' ><center> "+v.ext_ares+"</center></td>" +
              "<td class='lc_ownerdetail_1' ><center> "+cnt_OwnrName+"</center></td>"+val+"" +
              "<div id='td_select' style='display: block'>" +
              "<td class='selectall'><center>" +
              "<input type = 'checkbox'  class='chkNumber' value='"+JSON.stringify(v)+"' id = check"+sno+" " +
              " name=check"+sno+" onClick='addSave(this); ;' /></center></td>"
```

for example:

```
<input id="check1" class="chkNumber" type="checkbox" onclick="addSave(this); ;" name="check1" value="{"patta":275,"authorityno":1,"villageCode":"057","ownersChitta":}"

<input id="check2" class="chkNumber" type="checkbox" onclick="addSave(this); ;" name="check2" value="{ "flag": "No records"}"
```

Am newbie how can i check ???

Comment: Please make **jsfiddle** for more understanding...

Answer (score 1):

Try this : bind change event to the 'No Record' checkbox and disabled other checkbox if it is checked or enable when not checked. use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** to make disabled / enabled checkbox

```
$(function(){
  $('#check2').change(function(){
    $('.chkNumber').not(this).prop('disabled',this.checked);
  });
});
```

**EDIT** - As OP said, id would not be same every time but value of 'No Record' checkbox will be same. Below is my updated solution

```
$(function(){
      $('.chkNumber').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == '{ "flag": "No records"}')
          $('.chkNumber').not(this).prop('disabled',this.checked);
      });
 });
```

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead `.attr()`

Comment: @Satpal, thanks ... I have updated my answer as per your suggestion. But would like to know why to use `.prop()` as it introduced in version 1.6 is the only reason or is there some other reason to follow it? If you can share a link or post some details about it, would be helpful to me. Thanks :)

Comment: See [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: @Satpal, thank you very much for sharing this link and clearing my doubts :)

Comment: $('#check2') it not constant i can have many row so at the time it had change but the value wil be same so according to value only we need to restrict the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(".chkNumber").change(function() {
  var self = this;
  $(".chkNumber").prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```